# How to enhance standard FIORI app even though there are no extesnion points

Tags: sapui5

There is requirement to enhance standard FIORI app, but there are no extension hooks available on FIORI apps library .Kindly clarify can we enhance Standrad FIORI app without extension point.

Comment: Can you [link](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/home) the application your talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "View Replacement"

> If the extension points provided [...] are not sufficient to meet the requirements of the custom application [or no extension points provided], you can replace the standard view with a custom view.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/98861cf90b874e3394b666cfb347ff0b